# Grep behaving differently in OpenBSD to Linux. Cannot get command working

Tags: regex, linux, grep, openbsd

So basically what this command does is securely connect to a web domain to grab my external IP address, this works flawlessly on a Linux Debian system, but it is not working right on my OpenBSD system.  Curl command works fine, however something is up with the Grep command as it just isn't grabbing the IP that curl is piping to it..

Does -Eo not work with OpenBSD? I cannot tell with the man page..

```
USERAGENT="Mozilla/4.0"
WEB_LOCATION="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=whats+my+ip"

curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 5 -tlsv1.2 --user-agent $USERAGENT $WEB_LOCATION | grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}\>'
```

******* RESOLVED (Kinda) ********

I worked out that for some reason this particular pattern :

```
grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}\>'
```

was not working on OpenBSD, but this long version does..

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

Why this is the case is very confusing, as the first search pattern works fine on all the versions of Debian Linux I have used!

Comment: Define "isn't working"? Does it just not match? Does it error? Does it return too much?

Comment: It returns nothing at all, no errors. Adding ; echo $? to the end of the command returns an error code of 1

Comment: You've checked that `curl` is returning the correct value?

Comment: `grep` returns 1 when no lines have been output so that doesn't say much.

Comment: Curl command is working fine, I can see my IP in the stdoutput, along with tons of other stuff like CSS code etc..

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'm completely stumped by this grep command not working on OpenBSD.

Comment: Your `grep` will get any number in the form of `x.x.x.x`, so it also get `433.921.466.1`

Comment: I partially resolved this issue already, edited the question with details..

Answer (score 7):

The issue is with the word boundary patterns in your regexp, which are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` in OpenBSD but `\<` and `\>` respectively in Debian (and possibly other Linux distributions).

```
grep -Eo '[[:<:]][[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}[[:>:]]'
```

should work.

Read [the man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-5.6/man7/re_format.7) for details.